# Unable to parse json into list of custom Java objects

Tags: java, json, parsing, jsonpath

I am reading JSON from a file, and when trying to unmarshal the file to a java object, I am not getting expected array of custom Java object, however, getting array of LinkedHashMap

Please see below objects

```
    public class Result<T>{
        private final Map<String, T> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
         public Map<String, T> getAccounts(){
             return accounts;
         }
    }

JSON ->
{
   "data":{
     "account":[
           {
               "accountDetails":{
                      "accountId":"123",
                      "accountType":"Decon"
               }
           },
           {
               "accountDetails":{
                      "accountId":"890",
                      "accountType":"ACX"
               }
           },
           {
               "accountDetails":{
                      "accountId":"123",
                      "accountType":"OOOP"
               }
           }
     ]
   }
}


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Accounts{
   
   @Getter
   @Setter
   public static class AcountDetails{
      private String accountId;
      private String accountType;
   }
}
```

I am trying to read this Json as below

```
 String accounts = Resource.asByteSource(Resources.getResource("account.json")).asCharSource(Charsets.UTF_8).read();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Result<List<Accounts> finalResult = mapper.readValue(accounts, Result.class);



 In finalResult variable , 
    
    I am getting a map with key as "account" and value as list
    But, instead of List of "Accounts" object, I am getting list of **LinkedHashMap**
```

So bascially after parsing, Instead of getting array of Accounts objects, I am getting array of LinkedHashMap

Please find attached screenshot. Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after changing

```java
Result<List<Accounts> finalResult = mapper.readValue(accounts, Result.class);
```

to

```java
Result<List<Accounts>> finalResult = mapper.readValue(accounts, new TypeReference<Result<List<Accounts>>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get an Array of objects, your JSON would have to look something like this:

```
"element": [
{
  "element1": "Value 1",
  "element2": "Value 1"
},
{
  "element1": "Value 1",
  "element2": "Value 1"
}
]
```

When you are defining another object as you did:

```
"account":[
       {
           "accountDetails":{
                  "accountId":"123",
                  "accountType":"Decon"
           }
       },
```

You are creating a List of an Object that contains two more Objects. In Java that's a Map.
List<Map<AccountId, AccountType>

Hope it helps

**Edit for formatting purposes if "Element1" were another Object:**

```
"element": [
{
  "element1": {
    "element3": "Value",
    "element4": "Value"
  },
  "element2": "Value 1"
},
{
  "element1": "Value 1",
  "element2": "Value 1"
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would you write JSON, if "element1 was a custom object?

Comment: @Nishant In this case "element" would be the custom Object containing 2 Variables "element1" and "element2". The example Shows: 'List<Element>' in Json. If "element1" should be another Object, you would add it as usual.
{
"element1": {
"value": "value"
},
"element2": "value"
}

Comment: Thats what I have. Only extra I have is {
   "data":{   Did you mean I should remove "data" and have the rest?

Comment: @Nishant please Edit your Question to make it clear what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all can you confirm what you want to do here:

> `Map final Map<String, T> accounts = new LinkedHashMap<>();`
> inside class Result? Because if it is a variable, then remove the leading *Map* and don't make the variable as final.
> Also you will need both setters and getters for the variable.

Secondly, your json has 'data' which has a account: [] pair, so first read value from data, then from account and you will get the list.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. -? changed from accounts to data.  This is what i have now private final Map<String, T> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();

Comment: I am able to read accounts. Only issue is that instead of Array of Accouts objects, I am seeing Array of LinkedHashMap. Please se screenshot attached

Comment: @Nishant Can't see any screenshots attached